# How to determine the correlation between two normal random variables conditioned on their sum being negative?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution

Suppose we have two independent and identically distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$, both following the standard normal distribution. We take $1,000,000$ sample pairs and want to determine the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ in the pairs where $X + Y < 0$.

I have performed a simulation-based approach and my results suggest that the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ in these pairs is less than $0$. However, I am wondering if there is a mathematical way to show this result.

Any insights and mathematical arguments would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b I corrected it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conditional expectations of $X$ and $Y$ are obviously equal.  Moreover, because $(X+Y)/\sqrt 2$ has a standard Normal distribution, its conditional expectation is the negative of $-|Z|$ where $Z$ is standard normal, whence

$$E((X+Y)/\sqrt 2\mid X+Y \lt 0) = -E[|Z|] = -\frac{2}{\sqrt {2\pi}} = -\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi},$$

from which we obtain

$$E[X \mid X+Y \lt 0] = E[Y \mid X+Y \lt 0] = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}.$$

Notice that

$$E[XY\mid X+Y\lt 0] = \frac{1}{2}E[XY\mid X+Y\lt 0, X \gt Y] + \frac{1}{2} E[XY\mid X+Y\lt 0, X\lt Y] = 0.$$

Since $(X+Y)^2/2$ has a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution,

$$\begin{aligned}
2 &= E[(X+Y)^2\mid X+Y\lt 0] = E[(X+Y)^2\mid X+Y\lt 0] \\&= E[X^2\mid X+Y\lt 0] + 2E[XY\mid X+Y\lt 0] + 2E[Y^2\mid X+Y\lt 0]\\&= 2 E[X^2\mid X+Y\lt 0] + 2E[XY\mid X+Y\lt 0]\\
&= 2 E[X^2\mid X+Y\lt 0].
\end{aligned}$$

Consequently

$$\operatorname{Var}(X\mid X+Y\lt 0) = 1 - \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\right)^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{\pi} = \operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X+Y\lt 0)$$

and

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y\mid X+Y\lt 0) = 0 - \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\right)^2 = -\frac{1}{\pi}.$$

Therefore

> $$\operatorname{Cor}(X,Y\mid X+Y\lt 0) = \frac{-1/\pi}{1 - 1/\pi} = -\frac{1}{\pi-1}.$$

Here is an `R` simulation confirming this result.

```R
set.seed(17)
n <- 1e8
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n)
i <- x + y < 0
signif(c(cor(x[i], y[i]),-1/(pi-1)), 4)
```

> [1] -0.4668 -0.4669

The empirical correlation and the formula differ by only a small amount attributable to sampling variation.

Comment: Thanks @whuber! Brilliant calculation!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ is a probability space on which a random variable $\xi$ is defined with $E[|\xi|] < \infty$, this is an interesting problem that reflects the connection between two concepts:  $E[\xi|A]$ (where $A$ is an event with $P(A) > 0$) and $E[\xi|\mathscr{G}$] (where $\mathscr{G}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathscr{F}$).  The latter concept is the general measure-theoretic conditional expectation, while the former concept is less often seen (in probability).

Rigorously, $E[\xi|A]$ should be interpreted as $\int_\Omega \xi dP^*$, where the probability measure $P^*$ is defined by (see [this related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128937/prove-conditional-expectation-exxx-is-the-unconditional-expectation-e-p/128941#128941)):
\begin{align}
P^*(B) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}, \quad B \in \mathscr{F}. 
\end{align}
Therefore, unlike $E[\xi|\mathscr{G}]$ which is a r.v., $E[\xi|A]$ is a non-random number.  It can be shown that$^\dagger$:
\begin{align}
E[\xi | A] = \frac{E[\xi I_A]}{P(A)}. \tag{1}
\end{align}

By the law of iterative expectations, the numerator of the right-hand side of $(1)$ equals to $E[E[\xi I_A|\mathscr{G}]]$. If we further know that $A \in \mathscr{G}$ hence $I_A$ is $\mathscr{G}$-measurable, then $I_A$ can be pulled out from the inner conditional expectation, results in
\begin{align}
E[\xi | A] = \frac{E[I_AE[\xi|\mathscr{G}]]}{P(A)}.
\end{align}
This is the connection between $E[\xi|A]$ and $E[\xi|\mathscr{G}]$, which is the backbone of calculations below (with $\mathscr{G} = \sigma(Z)$).

Given $X, Y \text{ i.i.d.} \sim N(0, 1)$, denote $X + Y \sim N(0, 2)$ by $Z$ and $[Z < 0]$ by $A$, our interest is to compute
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Corr}(X, Y|A) = \frac{E[XY|A] - E[X|A]E[Y|A]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X|A)\operatorname{Var}(Y|A)}}, \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
where $\operatorname{Var}(X|A) = E[X^2|A] - (E[X|A])^2$.

By the [affine transformation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation) of the multivariate normal distribution, we have
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Z \end{bmatrix} \overset{d}{=} 
\begin{bmatrix} Y \\ Z \end{bmatrix} \sim 
N_2\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}\right)
\end{align}
[whence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) $X | Z \overset{d}{=} Y | Z \sim N(Z/2, 1/2)$.  Hence
\begin{align}
E[X | Z] = \frac{Z}{2}, \;
\operatorname{Var}(X | Z) = \frac{1}{2}, \;
E[X^2 | Z] = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}Z^2. \tag{2}
\end{align}

The last preparation is to compute $P(A), E[ZI_A]$ and $E[Z^2I_A]$, which by $Z \sim N(0, 2)$ are respectively (where $\varphi$ denotes the density of $N(0, 1)$):
\begin{align}
& P(A) = P(Z < 0) = \frac{1}{2}, \\
& E[ZI_A] = \int_{-\infty}^0 t\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\varphi(t/\sqrt{2}) dt = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \\
& E[Z^2I_A] = \int_{-\infty}^0 t^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\varphi(t/\sqrt{2}) dt = \frac{1}{2}E[Z^2] = 1. \tag{3}
\end{align}

Note that as $I_A$ is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable, it follows by the law of iterative expectations and $(2)$ -- $(3)$ that
\begin{align}
& E[XI_A] = E[E[XI_A|Z]] = E[I_AE[X|Z]] = \frac{1}{2}E[ZI_A] = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}, \tag{4} \\
& E[X^2I_A] = E[E[X^2I_A|Z]] = E[I_AE[X^2|Z]] = \frac{1}{2}P(A) + \frac{1}{4}E[Z^2I_A] = \frac{1}{2}. \tag{5}
\end{align}

To compute $E[XYI_A]$, write $XY = \frac{1}{2}(Z^2 - (X - Y)^2)$, and use the fact that $Z$ and $X - Y$ [are independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625714/are-the-random-variables-x-y-and-x-y-independent-if-x-y-are-distribut/1625748#1625748), it follows that
\begin{align}
E[XY|Z] = \frac{1}{2}Z^2 - \frac{1}{2}E[(X - Y)^2|Z] = 
\frac{1}{2}Z^2 - \frac{1}{2}E[(X - Y)^2] = \frac{1}{2}Z^2 - 1, 
\end{align}
which implies, by applying the law of iterative expectations and $(3)$ that
\begin{align}
E[XYI_A] = \frac{1}{2}E[Z^2I_A] - P(A) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} = 0. \tag{6}
\end{align}

By $(1)$, $P(A) = 1/2$ and symmetry, $(4)$ -- $(6)$ then yield
\begin{align}
& E[X|A] = E[Y|A] = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \tag{7} \\
& \operatorname{Var}(X|A) = \operatorname{Var}(Y|A) = 
E[X^2|A] - (E[X|A])^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{\pi}, \tag{8} \\ 
& E[XY|A] = 0. \tag{9}
\end{align}

Substituting $(7)$ -- $(9)$ into $(*)$ gives
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Corr}(X, Y|A) = 
\frac{0 - \frac{1}{\pi}}{1 - \frac{1}{\pi}} = 
-\frac{1}{\pi - 1}.
\end{align}

---

$^\dagger$:  Verify $(1)$ successively for indicator functions, simple functions, nonnegative r.v. and general integrable r.v.