# Finding the conditional expectation given the joint density function

Tags: conditional-expectation, joint-distribution, triangular-distribution

> Suppose a random vector $(X, Y )$ has joint probability density function $f(x, y)=3y$ on the triangle bounded by the lines $y = 0, y = 1 − x$, and $y =1+ x.$ Compute $E(Y \mid X ≤ 1/2 ).$

I'm confused about how to write the range of integral for obtaining the marginal distribution of $x$. After plotting it, I found that $y$ varies from $0$ to $1$. But again, it also depends on the value of $x$, like when $x=0.5, y=0.5$. What am I missing and what is a general method for obtaining the ranges?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know the equation
\begin{align}
E[Y|X \leq 1/2] = \frac{E[YI_{[X \leq 1/2]}]}{P[X \leq 1/2]}, \tag{1}
\end{align}
you can skip the step of finding the conditional density $f_{Y|X \leq 1/2}$ by working with the joint density $f(x, y) = 3y$ over the shaded region below (call it $S$ hereafter) directly:

[image: region S]

Specifically, just evaluate the following two integrals:

1. Integrating $f(x, y) = 3y$ over $S$ to get $P[X \leq 1/2]$.
2. Integrating $yf(x, y) = 3y^2$ over $S$ to get $E[YI_{[X \leq 1/2]}]$.

By the linearity of integrals, for each task, it is equivalent to integrating the integrand over regions $S_1$ and $S_2$ then add them up, where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are shaded regions below respectively:

[image: region S1] [image: region S2]

After setting up this roadmap, now let's deal with the calculations:
\begin{align}
& P[X \leq 1/2] = \iint_{S_1}3ydxdy + \iint_{S_2}3ydxdy \\
=& \int_{-1}^0\left[\int_0^{1 + x}3ydy\right]dx + 
\int_0^{1/2}\left[\int_0^{1 - x}3ydy\right]dx \\
=& \frac{3}{2}\int_{-1}^0 (1 + x)^2dx + 
\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{1/2}(1 - x)^2dx \\
=& \frac{1}{2} + \frac{7}{16} \\
=& \frac{15}{16}. \tag{2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
& E[YI_{[X \leq 1/2]}] = \iint_{S_1}3y^2dxdy + \iint_{S_2}3y^2dxdy \\
=& \int_{-1}^0\left[\int_0^{1 + x}3y^2dy\right]dx + 
\int_0^{1/2}\left[\int_0^{1 - x}3y^2dy\right]dx \\
=& \int_{-1}^0 (1 + x)^3dx + 
\int_0^{1/2}(1 - x)^3dx \\
=& \frac{1}{4} + \frac{15}{64} \\
=& \frac{31}{64}. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Substituting $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$ then gives
\begin{align}
E[Y|X \leq 1/2] = \frac{31/64}{15/16} = \frac{31}{60}. 
\end{align}

Comment: While both the answers are correct, this teaches, imo, a much broader and a noble approach that can come handy in many more problems.

Comment: Btw, I forgot to add that I edited your post to add a word with respect to the figures. If you feel it is not needed, feel free to undo it.

Comment: Thanks! Is the first equation a general result? Is it derived like this: $E(YI)=E(YI|I=1)P(I=1)+E(YI|I=0)P(I=0) \implies E(YI)=E(Y|X \leq \frac{1}{2})P(X \leq \frac{1}{2})$ ?

Comment: @Tapi The derivation in your comment is indeed correct since $E(Y\,I \mid I=0)P(I=0) =0$.  I like to note that $\frac{E[Y\,I_{[X \leq 1/2]}]}{P[X \leq 1/2]}$ can be written as $\frac{E[Y\,I_{[X \leq 1/2]}]}{E[I_{[X \leq 1/2]}]}$

Comment: @User1865345 Thank you for the edits.  I am also interested to learn is it possible to place the plots of $S_1$ and $S_2$ side by side in the same row?

Comment: @Zhanxiong, aren't the plots in the same row?

Comment: @User1865345 Not for me.  Probably the effect is device-dependent?

Comment: @Zhanxiong, this is the snap of desktop version in my phone: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t8XKl.jpg).

Comment: @User1865345 Thanks.  Let it be then.

Comment: In fact, this is the right way you [wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265999/19518994) @Zhanxiong.

Comment: @Tapi I would like to argue as follows (the argument you used itself needs to be proved): for a given event $A$ with $P(A) > 0$, the conditional density $f(x|A)$ is $f(x)I_A(x)/P(A)$, which implies $E[X|A] = \int xf(x|A)dx = E[XI_A]/P(A)$.  For more technical discussion on the notion of $E[X|A]$, see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/610271/how-to-determine-the-correlation-between-two-normal-random-variables-conditioned/610489#610489) too.

Comment: +1 for the picture.  But my comment to the first answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/615600/finding-the-conditional-expectation-given-the-joint-density-function/615605#comment1143971_615605 shows how to obtain the answer (using this technique) without integration, without Calculus, and without *Mathematica* ;-).

Comment: @whuber Very insightful observation.

Answer (score 8):

I would refer to the marginal distribution of (capital) $X$ rather than to the marginal distribution of (lower-case) $x.$ The former is the random variable, and those are the things that have distributions.

For any fixed value of $x,$ the other variable $y$ goes from $0$ to $1+x$ if $x\le0$ or from $0$ to $1-x$ if $x\ge0.$ So
\begin{align}
\Pr(X\le 1/2) & = \Pr(X\le0) + \Pr(0<X\le1/2) \\[8pt]
& = \frac12 + \Pr(0<X\le1/2), \text{ by symmetry} \\[8pt]
& = \frac12 + \int_0^{1/2} \left( \int_0^{1-x} 3y \,dy \right) \,dx \\[8pt]
& = \frac12 + \int_0^{1/2} \frac{3(1-x)^2} 2 \, dx \\[8pt]
& = \frac12 + \frac7{16} = \frac{15}{16}.
\end{align}
So the conditional joint density of $(X,Y)$ given $X\le1/2$ is
\begin{align}
& f_{X,Y\,\mid\,X\,\le\,1/2} (x,y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \begin{cases} (16/5)y & \text{if } \big(1<x<0 \text{ and } 0<y<1+x\big) \\ & \text{or } \big( 0<x<1/2 \text{ and } 0<y<1-x\big), \\[8pt] 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
\end{align}
And so
\begin{align}
& \operatorname E(Y\mid X\le1/2) \\[8pt]
= {} & \iint\limits_\text{triangle} y\cdot f_{X,Y\,\mid\,X\,\le\,1/2}(x,y) \, d(x,y) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{-1}^0 \left( \int_0^{1+x} y\cdot\frac{16}5 y \, dy \right) \, dx + \int_0^{1/2} \left( \int_0^{1-x} y \cdot \frac{16}5 y \, dy \right) \, dx.
\end{align}

Comment: +1. As a check, it's easy to see the regression of $y$ on $x$ is linear in each half of the triangle, which immediately implies the conditional expectation of $Y$ for $X\gt 1/2$ is one-half the unconditional expectation, equal to $1/2$; and scaling/units analysis easily shows the probability of the missing region $X\gt 1/2$ must be $1/2^3$ of the probability of its half of the triangle, whence by symmetry it equals $1/16$ (consistent with the first half of this answer). Consequently the solution $y_0=E[Y\mid X\le 1/2]$ satisfies $y_0(1-1/16) + (1/2)(1/2)(1/16)=1/2,$ yielding $y_0=31/60.$

Comment: Bit confused about the last step, usually when we have the pdf of an R.V. $X$, and we are to find the expectation we integrate $xf_X(x)$ over the range. Similarly, here we have the pdf of what we need to find the expectation of. So why the double integral? Is it because the range of values over which we are integrating depends on $x$?
Also, you missed the negative sign $(-1<x<0)$ in the conditional joint density.

Comment: @Tapi : I've added one intermediate step (which shows something that is technically a double integral rather than an iterated integral, if one wishes to be fastidious). One could also find the marginal conditional distribution of $Y$ given the event $X\le1/2$ and then find $$ \int_0^1 y\cdot f_{Y\,\mid\,X\,\le\,1/2}(y)\,dy $$ and the result would be the same.

Comment: @whuber really like your way of using symmetry, understood $P(X< 1/2)=1/16$, but could you explain why the regression of $y$ on $x$ is linear in each half of the triangle?
And how we're getting "the conditional expectation of $Y$ for $X>1/2$ is one-half the unconditional expectation, equal to $1/2$"? Also I don't know how to picture regression of $y$ on $x$, I just know it's $E(Y|X)$.

Comment: It comes down to considering how the distribution *on the right hand side of the triangle only* changes when you simultaneously rescale $x$ and $y$ by the same amount, *using $x=1$ as the origin.*