# Converting a Conditional Expectation into an Unconditional one

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Consider two random variables $V_1$ and $V_2$, where $V_1$ is continuous and $V_2$ is binary.

In a paper, I found that the following equality holds:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[V_1|V_2=1\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{V_2}{\mathbb{E}[V_2]}V_1\right]
\end{align*}
I remember that I have proved that this equality holds without any assumption about two years ago.

But, I cannot come up with the proof again.

So, does that equality holds always? or other assumptions are needed?

Comment: You should include reference or link to that paper!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for any random variable $X$ and an event $A$ with $P(A) > 0$, $E[X|A]$ is defined as (see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128937/prove-conditional-expectation-exxx-is-the-unconditional-expectation-e-p/128941#128941), [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/610271/how-to-determine-the-correlation-between-two-normal-random-variables-conditioned/610489#610489) and [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/615600/finding-the-conditional-expectation-given-the-joint-density-function/615628#615628) for related discussions):
\begin{align}
E[X|A] = \frac{E[XI_A]}{P(A)}. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Now taking $X = V_1$ and $A = [V_2 = 1]$ in $\eqref{1}$, and using the fact that $V_2$ is binary (so that $I_{[V_2 = 1]} = V_2$ and $P(V_2 = 1) = E[V_2]$) completes the proof.

Comment: Precisely stated.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very clear.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Dear Zhanxiong, I have an additional question. As you explained $E\left[V_1|V_2=1\right]=E\left[\frac{V_2}{E[V_2]}V_1\right]$ hold. Then, is there any way to convert the conditional mean to an unconditional one? For example, if we multiply $E[V_2]$ into $V_1$, then $E\left[V_1|V_2=1\right]=E\left[V_2V_1\right]$, which is still not $E[V_1]$.

Comment: @MinChulPark Isn't $E[V_2V_1]$ already an unconditional expectation? Of course you cannot expect $E[V_1|V_2 = 1] = E[V_1]$ in general (which holds when $V_1$ and $V_2$ are independent).