# Product of two random variables (one continuous, one discrete)

Tags: expected-value

I am interested in computing the following expected value: $E[yz]$, with $z$ taking values 0 or 1 so that $E[z]=Pr(Z=1)\equiv p$. The random variable $y$ is continuous and in general correlated with $z$.

From some prior lecture notes, I have that the following should hold:

$$E[yz] = E[y|z=1]p$$

I am sure this is trivial, but could you please elaborate why that should be the case?
It's clear that $E[y] = E[y|z=1]p + E[y|z=0](1-p)$, but I don't see how the $E[yz]$ result above should hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument goes no different from how you treated $E[Y]$, the idea is always to decompose the random variable of interest on two non-overlapping regions:
\begin{align}
YZ = YZI_{\{Z = 0\}} + YZI_{\{Z = 1\}} = YI_{\{Z = 1\}}. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
The second equality is of course due to that $Y \cdot 0 = 0$ and $Y \cdot 1 = Y$.

Now taking expectations on both sides of $\eqref{1}$, and applying the conditional expectation definition (when the conditioning object is an event) $E[\xi|A] = E[\xi I_A]/P(A)$ (see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/128937/prove-conditional-expectation-exxx-is-the-unconditional-expectation-e-p/128941#128941), [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/620995/converting-a-conditional-expectation-into-an-unconditional-one/621000#621000) for more details), it follows that
\begin{align}
E[YZ] = E[YI_{\{Z = 1\}}] = E[Y|Z = 1]P(Z = 1) = E[Y|Z = 1]p,
\end{align}
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Is it perhaps because $yz=0$ when $z=0$?

Edit: to clarify, $E[yz] = (1*E[y|z=1]*p) + (0*E[y|z=0]*(1-p)) = E[y|z=1]p$